# AJAX talking to PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am struggling with getting AJAX to work with a form, passing data through to some PHP/MySQL.

Here is the code - HTML:

```
<form id="<?=$applicationKey?>" name="<?=$applicationKey?>" action="./post.<?=$appNo?>.<?=$applicationKey?>.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="uID" value="<?=$uID?>">
<input type="hidden" name="uaID" value="<?=$uaID?>">
<input type="hidden" name="appID" value="<?=$appID?>">

<input type="text" id="input_1_1" name="input_1_1" placeholder="Name of the Applicant's Organisation" value="<?=$input_1_1?>" required>
<input type="text" id="input_1_2" name="input_1_2" placeholder="First Name" value="<?=$input_1_2?>" required>
<input type="text" id="input_1_3" name="input_1_3" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?=$input_1_3?>" required>
```

Etc (I'm sure you don't need the entire form listed out here). I have this JS as a separate .js file, loaded in the header of the HTML:

```
function doSend_1_1() {
$.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_1', $('#input_1_1').serialize());
}

function doSend_1_2() {
$.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_2', $('#input_1_2').serialize());
}

function doSend_1_3() {
$.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_3', $('#input_1_3').serialize());
}

$("document").ready(function() {
$("#input_1_1").blur(doSend_1_1);
$("#input_1_2").blur(doSend_1_2);
$("#input_1_3").blur(doSend_1_3);
})
```

And this sort of works well. When a user leaves either of the three fields, it does try to throw the data through to the PHP and make it do what I want it to do. The PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
include './conf/Funcs.php'; // Grab our functions
include './conf/DBconfig.php'; // Useful to have access to the database

$appID = $_GET['appID']; // identifies what entry we are talking to in the DB
$ident = $_GET['ident']; // defines what field is being posted

if(($ident) == "input_1_1") {
$userInput = $_POST['input_1_1'];
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_ConSupAp SET `organisation` = :userinput AND `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
    $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
    $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
    $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}
?>
```

As I have not successfully got it working for the first input field I've not added sections in the php for using the other fields as yet. So yes they are currently missing.

Firebug reports there are no problems, and the information in the organisation field within the database does change from it's previously preset entry to "0" - not what I type into the input field. Also the time() stamp does not update even when the weird 0 value is input into the database. With no errors and Firebug seemingly happy, I'm at a loss as to why my data is not being inserted correctly. Firebug does report that whatever is input into the text field is passed correctly to the php. Any ideas exactly what it is that is going wrong?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is being utilised, loaded in the originating page head. The database is MySQL. All php communication with the DB is done using PDO.

Comment: try to replace `AND` with comma in your DB query. Also replace: `lastModified = :time` with: `lastModified = now()` , as it doesn't require any processing.

Comment: phillip100 - fantastic, a slight DB error overlooked in the confusion of my ajax usage for the first time. Thank you! Would you mind please setting your answer up as an answer so I can credit you with getting it right?

In regards to using now() in the DB query, the reason I use time() is because I have a different timezone from the server, set in php and this ensures it stamps with the modified time zone and not the server default.

Comment: Also, you have a `post` form but are retrieving the variables using `$_GET`. (Ah, it looks like you have a hidden field and are passing them in the query string. You don't need both).

Comment: Not all the variables, only a couple of constants that I can pass easily via GET. This does not break anything.

Comment: Hi there @Cassandra. I just happened to notice a clean-up I made on your question a couple of days ago was reverted. It's quite normal for this to happen here - questions are a bit like wikis, and anyone can edit them. Since questions are kept here to be of use to future readers, we like to 'Wikipedia' them a bit and make them as readable as possible - hence case/paragraphing/spelling/formatting fixes are sometimes made.

Comment: Hello @halfer. I do understand this however all too frequently there is no necessity or requirement for unknown people to edit questions. Sadly too many do it because they simply can, not because they should. I believe it is VERY important for future readers to see, understand and realise that these questions are asked by people just like them. Not textbook tech perfectionists. For someone seeking help, it can be exceptionally off-putting to think they cannot type the jargon perfectly, and this is destructive to the purpose of SO. I'm happy for edits that help, but these such edits do not.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on it. In general, it's not about "tech perfectionism" but having a good level of readability (and arguably it will never be perfect). For what it's worth, I've been on the site a few years, and despite the great care I take over them, I am happy to let any good edits persist on my questions. And it's worth remembering that most editors mean well - they wish to contribute to the community, rather than criticise your work `:-)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in that line:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_ConSupAp SET `organisation` = :userinput AND `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
```

`AND` operator shouldn't be in that place. Repalace it with *comma*.

You could also set the `time()` directly in your query, as it doesn't have to be prepared

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_ConSupAp SET organisation = :userinput , lastModified = '".time()."' WHERE appID = :appid");
```

Comment: Thanks phillip100, a simple error on my part but kindly and quickly answered. Much appreciated! :)